# Getting parameter value in request in Multipart file upload form request

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

I have a form in JSP

```
                   <form action="/view/tool/Process" method="post"
                        enctype="multipart/form-data" target="_blank">
                        <p class="bottomPadded">&nbsp;</p>
                        <input type="file" name="file" /> 
                        <input id="fileprogramtype" type="text" name="programtype" style="display: none;"/>
                        <p class="bottomPadded">&nbsp;</p>
                        <p class="generalContent bottomPadded"><input class="imageBtn" type="image" name="image" src="/images/upload.png" /></p>
                    </form>
```

For this the request is mapped as

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ProcessUpload</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>view.tool.servlet.ProcessUpload</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ProcessUpload</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/view/tool/Process</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Any idea How can I get the value of `<input id="fileprogramtype" type="text" name="programtype" style="display: none;"/>` in ProcessUpload

I tried `request.getParamter("programtype")`, Its returning null.

I even tried

```
Collection<Part> parts = request.getParts();

            for(Part p : parts) {
                logger.info("Parts ::: "+p.getName());
                if ("programtype".equals(p.getName()))
                {
                    InputStream inputStream = p.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                    programtype = br.readLine();
                    logger.info("Here is Program Type ::"+programtype);
                }
            }
```

Its not even getting inside loop.

Can someone tell me in case of multipart form request how to get value of other parameters?

Answer (score 2):

While using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` you can not directly get parameters by using `request.getParameter("programtype")`;.

In this case the form fields aren't available as parameter of the request, they are included in the stream, so you need to get them from stream. A possible way is to use [commons-fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload//using.html). Here is sample code from official documentation ( Refer to 'Processing the uploaded items' section)

```
// Process the uploaded items
Iterator<FileItem> iter = items.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    FileItem item = iter.next();

    if (item.isFormField()) {
        processFormField(item);
    } else {
        processUploadedFile(item);
    }
}
```

For a regular form field

```
 // Process a regular form field if (item.isFormField()) {
     String name = item.getFieldName();
     String value = item.getString();
     ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea How can I get the value of `<input id="fileprogramtype"
>   type="text" name="programtype" style="display: none;"/>` in
>   ProcessUpload

Yes you can get by 
 `request.getParameter("programtype");`

Are you sure you are getting `null` because according to [Java Doc for ServletRequest#getRequestParameter method](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String))

> Returns the value of a request parameter as a String, or null if the
>   parameter does not exist. Request parameters are extra information
>   sent with the request. For HTTP servlets, parameters are contained in
>   the query string or posted form data.

You can get a blank value if you are not setting the value manually since it is a hidden field but you will not get a null value.

**Answering the same after verifying the similar code in my DEV environment**

Comment: Did you try with multipart form data? Because it doesn't work with that

Comment: @tima Yes, I tried only with multipart form. Please check this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glraq.html).

Comment: That's strange, I'm getting `null` even if I configure the servlet using annotations.

Comment: Yes I am getting null.. I got the answer..